# Decide at runtime for sync or async response using Jersey

Tags: java, rest, asynchronous, jersey

Is it possible to decide at runtime whether a Jersey REST request to an resource endpoint should be handled synchronously or asynchronously? Let's take a simple example.

The synchronous version:

```
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public Response get() {
        return Response.ok("Hello there!").build();
    }
}
```

The asynchronous version:

```
@Path("resource")
public class Resource {
    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public void get(@Suspended final AsyncResponse r) {
        r.resume(Response.ok("Hello there!").build()); // usually called somewhere from another thread
    }
}
```

Depending on certain parameters, I would like to decide at runtime whether the GET request should be handled synchronously or asynchronously. The URL of the resource endpoint (`http://server/resource`) must be the same in both cases. Is this possible?

Of course, as you can see in the example above, the synchronous version can be faked in an asynchronous manner by simply calling `AsyncResponse.resume(...)`. However, I would to avoid the overhead of creating the asynchronous response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## A step back

The *JAX-RS Asynchronous Server API* is all about how the **container** will manage the request. But it will still hold the request and **won't affect the client experience**.

Quoting the Jersey documentation about the [Asynchronous Server API](https://jersey.github.io/documentation/latest/async.html):

> Note that the use of server-side asynchronous processing model will
>   not improve the request processing time perceived by the client. It
>   will however increase the throughput of the server, by releasing the
>   initial request processing thread back to the I/O container while the
>   request may still be waiting in a queue for processing or the
>   processing may still be running on another dedicated thread. The
>   released I/O container thread can be used to accept and process new
>   incoming request connections.

The approaches described below won't bring any benefits to your client.

### Using a custom header

You could have different URLs for sync and async methods and create a [pre-matching filter](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/filters-and-interceptors.html#d0e9726), which is executed before the request matching is started.

To do it, implement [`ContainerRequestFilter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestFilter.html), annotate it with [`@PreMatching`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/PreMatching.html) and, based on your conditions (headers, parameters, etc), change the requested URI:

```
@Provider
@PreMatching
public class PreMatchingFilter implements ContainerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext) throws IOException {

        if (requestContext.getHeaders().get("X-Use-Async") != null) {
            requestContext.setRequestUri(yourNewURI);
        }
    }
}
```

Have a look at the [`ContainerRequestContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html) [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html).

### Using a custom media type

I haven't tested the following solution, but it should work. You can keep the same URL for both sync and async methods, just accepting a different content type for each method.

For example:

- Sync method: `@Consumes("application/vnd.example.sync+text")`
- Async method: `@Consumes("application/vnd.example.async+text")`

And use the `PreMatchingFilter` to change the `Content-Type` header based on your conditions, like the following:

```
if (useSync) {
    requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle(
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.example.sync+text");
} else {
    requestContext.getHeaders().putSingle(
        HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/vnd.example.async+text");
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getHeaders--), [`ContainerRequestContext#getHeaders()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/container/ContainerRequestContext.html#getHeaders--) returns a mutable map with the request headers.

Comment: Thanks. Changing the content media type is a nice way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom MediaType...you can for example put @Produces("simple") on your simple get method and @Produces("asynch") on your asynchronous get method. In your client you then can set the Accept Header of your call to "simple" or "asynch" depending on what you need.